# should i use php's htmentities() with pdo to filter input and output escapeing?

Tags: php, xss

should i use php's htmentities() with pdo to filter input and output escapeing, to protect from xss attack ?

Comment: More important than when to encode are the second (ENT_QUOTES) and third parameter (charset) - to have the string escaped for use in any HTML tag and quoted attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `htmlentities` (or preferably `htmlspecialchars`) when **outputting** user supplied content in an HTML context (i.e. when displaying it on your website). Don't HTML escape values that go into the database, since there's no XSS vulnerability there and you usually want to store the *raw* data in the database and escape it later as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You should use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars before saving the input to the database, cause a text is saved to a database only once [until there is any edit option on the front end] but is viewed multiple times, so you save your CPU :)

Comment: CPU time is a valid counter argument, but if you ever use the data outside an HTML context (say, in a JSON API), you have to use all that CPU time to unescape everything. I'd always recommend storing raw data until the minuscule overhead of HTML escaping is proven to be a bottleneck and you're 100% sure you're only ever going to use the data in an HTML context.